# Two button form, each makes something different

Tags: php

I would like to ask, how can I build a form and php code which indicates when button1 pressed, include test.php and when button2 pressed open a new page.

What I have is this

```
...
<form name="frm_action" method="post" action="">
<div align="center">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal1" id="btn_getVal1" value="VAL1" tabindex="1">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal2" id="btn_getVal2" value="VAL2" tabindex="2">
</form>
...
 <?php 
   if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal1']))
   {
        include('test.php');
   }
   if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal2']))
   {
        header('location: test2.php');
        exit();
   }
 ?>
 ...
```

The first option (btn_getVal1) works perfect, the second one wont work. It shows everytime index.php.

How can I link to an internal .php page while pressig the button?

Comment: You can open a new page using javascript, the `header` function must must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your PHP code before the html like this:

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal1']))
   {
        include('test.php');
   }
   if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal2']))
   {
        header('location: test2.php');
        exit();
   }

?>

<form name="frm_action" method="post" action="">
<div align="center">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal1" id="btn_getVal1" value="VAL1" tabindex="1">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal2" id="btn_getVal2" value="VAL2" tabindex="2">
</form>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `header` function must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

To fix your header bug:

```
<?php
// only display form at first load or on push button 1
if (empty($_POST) || isset($_POST['btn_getVal1'])) {
?>
<form name="frm_action" method="post" action="">
<div align="center">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal1" id="btn_getVal1" value="VAL1" tabindex="1">
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal2" id="btn_getVal2" value="VAL2" tabindex="2">
</form>
<?php
} // close first if

if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal1'])) {
    include('test.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal2'])) {
    // in this case no html was print before so header works
    // you can add a peace of javascript here if you want open a new page.
    header('location: test2.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the php code in front of the html code, like this:

```
 <?php 
     if (isset($_POST['btn_getVal1']))
     {
         include('test.php');
     }
     elseif (isset($_POST['btn_getVal2']))
     {
         header('location: test2.php');
         exit();
     }
    else{
?>
<form name="frm_action" method="post" action="">
<div align="center">
    <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal1" id="btn_getVal1" value="VAL1" tabindex="1">
    <input type="submit" style="font-size: 1.5em;border: 1pt;" name="btn_getVal2" id="btn_getVal2" value="VAL2" tabindex="2">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: In this case the form is after including test.php…